# Animate CAShapeLayer setPath

Tags: ios, cashapelayer, cabasicanimation

I am trying to add animation while drawing a bezierPath. There is base circle darkgray (0 to 360) , green path (-90 to 0) and red path (0 to 90).

[image]

[image]

```
#import "ProgressBar.h"



@interface ProgressBar ()
{
    CAShapeLayer *lightGrayPath;
}



@end

@implementation ProgressBar

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self){
        [self initValues];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self){
        [self initValues];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self startAnimation];

}


-(void)initValues{
    lightGrayPath = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    lightGrayPath.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    lightGrayPath.lineWidth=2.0f;
    lightGrayPath.strokeColor =[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.1].CGColor;
    [self.layer addSublayer:lightGrayPath];
}


-(void)startAnimation{
    CGRect rect=self.bounds;
    CGFloat subPathWidth=10.0;
    UIBezierPath *bezierPath_lightGray=[UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    bezierPath_lightGray.lineWidth=lightGrayPath.lineWidth;

    [bezierPath_lightGray addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds)) radius:(rect.size.height / 2)- subPathWidth/2.0
                                startAngle:0 endAngle:2*M_PI clockwise:YES];









    UIBezierPath *bezierPath_green=[UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    bezierPath_green.lineWidth=subPathWidth;

    [[UIColor greenColor] setStroke];
    [bezierPath_green addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds)) radius:(rect.size.height / 2)- subPathWidth/2.0 startAngle:-M_PI/2.0     endAngle:0 clockwise:YES];
    [bezierPath_green stroke];
    [bezierPath_lightGray appendPath:bezierPath_green];


    UIBezierPath *bezierPath_red=[UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    bezierPath_red.lineWidth=subPathWidth;


    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
    [bezierPath_red addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds)) radius:(rect.size.height / 2)- subPathWidth/2.0 startAngle:0     endAngle:M_PI_2 clockwise:YES];
    [bezierPath_red stroke];
    [bezierPath_lightGray appendPath:bezierPath_red];


    lightGrayPath.path=bezierPath_lightGray.CGPath;


    //    CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
    //    pathAnimation.duration = 10.0;
    //    //pathAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    //    pathAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
    //    [lightGrayPath addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"path"];
}



@end
```

I want to show animation of path being drawn. The lightGrayArc should **not be animated**. The Green arc and the red arc should be.

But, Since I am using only one CAShapeLayer and appending paths to it. When i use animation , it animates the light gray path,  no animation for green and red arc.

Comment: BTW, when dealing with `CAShapeLayer`, you shouldn't be doing anything in `drawRect`. You'd generally do this in `awakeFromNIB` or an initializer method.

Comment: @Rob True, I am using it just for clarification purpose.

Comment: OK, but it doesn't clarify it at all. It only clouds the issue further. Never initiate animations from `drawRect`. The purpose of `drawRect` is to draw a single frame. I'm also still unclear as to the desired animation of green and blue arcs. Simultaneously? One after the other?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

1. Do not animate in `drawRect`. That's for drawing a single frame.
2. There are two ways to animate a path:

   - Don't use `CAShapeLayer` at all, but instead define a `drawRect` that performs `stroke` on one or more `UIBezierPath`.

     To animate, don't use `CABasicAnimation`, but rather use a `CADisplayLink` (a type of timer optimized for screen updates) that changes some properties that define where the path starts and ends and then call `setNeedsDisplay`, which will trigger a call to `drawRect` that will use those properties to `stroke` the path for that frame of the animation.
   - Even easier, don't use `drawRect` to stroke anything at all. Just add your gray, green, and red arcs as three different `CAShapeLayer` instances. Let `CAShapeLayer` do all the rendering of the arcs for you.

     When you want to animate the red and green layers, add `CABasicAnimation` for those respective layers.

Comment: I did think of different CAShapeLayer, but later on thought it would be a memory expensive operation. So, planned with one CAShapeLayer and adding paths to it and it would animate like first Green path should be animated, then as soon as its about to end, it should start Red path and once reached red, stop any animation.

Comment: The memory implications of three shape layers is inconsequential and it's much easier to do the desired animation. If you want to go `drawRect` approach, you'd retire `CAShapeLayer` entirely, and animate with `CADisplayLink`. But it's not worth the hassle here, IMHO.